# Error en DBExpress con Delphi + SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008

Estimados tengo este error :

```
  SQL STATE 42000, SQL Error CODE 201
```

Busque informacion en internet y no puedo encontrar la solucion.
Script del lado del cliente:

```
 var client : TTServerMethodsClient;
    var ds:TDataset;
    var dst:TDataset;
    var ch : char;
    var canti : String;
    var eproceso : String;
    var suma : Double;
    var multi:Double;
    var resultado : Double;

    begin
         client :=   TTServerMethodsClient.Create(SQLConnectionDTComprobantes.DBXConnection);
         ds := DBGridDTCompo.DataSource.DataSet;

         if not SQLConnectionDTComprobantes.Connected  then
                SQLConnectionDTComprobantes.Connected := True;



        fecha := ds.FieldByName('fecha').Value;
        numerocompo := ds.FieldByName('numero_comprobante').Value;
        codigo_producto := ds.FieldByName('codigo_producto').Value;
        valor_unitario := ds.FieldByName('valor_unitario').Value;
        canti :=  ds.FieldByName('cantidad').Value;
        eproceso :=  '1';

        try

  //INSERT        label2.Caption:=client.ProcedureSDTComprobantes(strToFloat(canti),codigo_producto,strToDateTime(fecha),numerocompo,strToFloat(valor_unitario),strToInt(eproceso));

        finally
         FreeAndNil(client);
        end;

    end;
```

Procedimiento SQLSERVER:

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[setComprobantes]
@numero_comprobante varchar(12),
@fecha datetime,
@codigo_producto varchar(10),
@cantidad decimal(15, 4),
@valor_unitario decimal(15, 4),
@eproceso int
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @variable INT



    SET @variable = (SELECT eproceso FROM detalle_comprobante WHERE eproceso = @eproceso);

    IF @variable=NULL

    INSERT INTO detalle_comprobante (numero_comprobante,fecha,cantidad, codigo_producto,valor_unitario,eproceso) 
    VALUES 
    (@numero_comprobante,@fecha,@cantidad,@codigo_producto,@valor_unitario,@eproceso);

    ELSE
        UPDATE detalle_comprobante
        SET 
            fecha = @fecha,
            codigo_producto =@codigo_producto, 
            cantidad =@cantidad, 
            valor_unitario =@valor_unitario,
            eproceso = @eproceso
            WHERE numero_comprobante=@numero_comprobante

END
```

Script del lado del Servidor:

```
function TTServerMethods.ProcedureSDTComprobantes(canti: Double; coditemsd: string; fechas : TDateTime; numcompro:String;  valorUnis:Double;const eproceso : Integer): String;
begin
 try
       if not EjemploDatasnap.Connected then
          EjemploDatasnap.Connected := true;


       if SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active then
          SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active := False;


       //SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Open;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('cantidad').AsString := floatToStr(canti);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('coditems').AsString := coditemsd;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('fecha').AsString := DateTimeToStr(fechas);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('numero_comprobante').AsString := numero_comprobante;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('valoruni').AsString := floatTostr(valorUnis);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('eproceso').AsString := intToStr(eproceso);
       //SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Close;

       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active := True;
       //SQLDataSetIProductos.Active:=False;



   except on
   E: Exception do
    Result := E.Message;
end;

end;
```

El error  esta cuando ejecuto el procedimiento, creo que los parámetros o algo me esta causando un error de conexión, pero no me doy cuenta donde esta ese error.

Comment: `SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('numcompo')` no debiera respetar el nombre del parámetro, es decir `numero_comprobante`? y así con cada uno.

Comment: SI es verdad, cambie los datos pero el error sigue....quise depurar con delphi pero no me deja el IDE.

Comment: Por favor necesito ayuda....

Comment: yo verificaría que el stored procedure funcione correctamente, si `eproceso=@eproceso` devuelve varias filas puede haber un error en el  `SET @variable = (SELECT eproceso...` , tal vez usar `IF NOT EXISTS` también verificar que no haya comillas doble pasadas en los `varchar`debido al `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`

Comment: No más por no dejar, pero si pruebas omitiendo el parámetro de la fecha, trata de quitar el parámetro que te comento tanto en tu código como el tu sql para ver si no esta tronando por el tipo de fecha que estas mandando, muchas veces solo es que el formato de la fecha que envías no es el mismo que espera recibir la bd

Answer (score 1):

El error al parecer está en que el procedimiento almacenado está esperando un parámetro que no le está llegando.

En la línea `SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('numero_comprobante').AsString := numero_comprobante;` no le estás asignando el valor que llega en el método, debería ser `SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('numero_comprobante').AsString := numcompro;`

Por lo que el método del lado del servidor quedaría así:

```
function TTServerMethods.ProcedureSDTComprobantes(canti: Double; coditemsd: string; fechas : TDateTime; numcompro:String;  valorUnis:Double;const eproceso : Integer): String;
   begin
   try
       if not EjemploDatasnap.Connected then
          EjemploDatasnap.Connected := true;

       if SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active then
          SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active := False;


       //SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Open;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('cantidad').AsString := floatToStr(canti);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('coditems').AsString := coditemsd;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('fecha').AsString := DateTimeToStr(fechas);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('numero_comprobante').AsString := numcompro;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('valoruni').AsString := floatTostr(valorUnis);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('eproceso').AsString := intToStr(eproceso);
       //SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Close;

       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active := True;
       //SQLDataSetIProductos.Active:=False;

    except on
    E: Exception do
    Result := E.Message;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: El error estaba en el procedimiento almacenando SQLServer y en TTServerMtehods.  Estaba llamando a parámetros que no los estaba teniendo en cuenta en ambas cosas. Es decir, llamaba a parámetros desde SqlServer que no los había tenido en cuenta en el método desarrollado en delphi.

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en el procedimiento almacenando **SQLServer** y en **TTServerMtehods**.

Estaba llamando a parámetros que no los estaba teniendo en cuenta en ambas cosas. Es decir, llamaba a parámetros desde SqlServer que no los había tenido en cuenta en el método desarrollado en delphi.